# CSS flex-box, how do I make an item stretch smaller than the content in the cross-axis direction?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a container with side-by-side divs, one item has a fixed width and the other item has a fixed height.  However, the flexible-height div won't shrink below its contents.

```css
.parent {
  background: #f00;
  display: contents;
}

.container {
  background: #0f0;
  width: 25vw;
  display: flex;
}

.object {
  background: #00f;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.object.flexes-main-axis {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.object.sets-cross-axis-size {
  height: 75px;
}

.object.shrinks-cross-axis-below-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.child {
  background: #f0f;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div id="object1" class='object flexes-main-axis sets-cross-axis-size'></div>
    <div id="object2" class='object shrinks-cross-axis-below-content'>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get object2 to shrink and show a vertical scroll bar when I shrink object1 below 100px. The magenta box represents fixed-height content I can’t shrink, while object1 represents the element I want to control the container’s height.

Comment: After some more experimentation and research, object2 will overflow as expected with height: 100%.  However, this is subject to the oft-frustrating limitation of the parent's height needing to be calculatable without reference to the children, which results in 100% instead being calculated as auto and is why I didn't see it before.  So, I can't control the entire container just with object1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out.  I needed to add an extra wrapper div between object2 and child with height set to 0.  Object2 will scroll to accommodate child overflow, but child's height won't count toward object2's content as far as the flexbox is concerned.  Now as you change object1's height below child's height, you'll get a scroll bar in object2.

Also in this version, I made object1 responsive to the viewport width, so you can try it out by resizing the browser window.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50vw;
}
.sizecontroller {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.sizeresponsive {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.sizeeraser {
  height: 0;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 10px;
}
.sizefixed {
  width: 25px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sizecontroller"></div>
  <div class="sizeresponsive">
    <div class="sizeeraser">
      <div class="sizefixed"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The blue is hardcoded `75px` tall, while the magenta is hardcoded `100px`.

As the main `.container` has no `height` set it will grow to fit the tallest child. A main `.container` with a fixed `height: ..px` would still not make `.child` shrink. That's Flexbox.

But, if you set the `.child` to `height: 100%` and you will see it shrink:

```css
* { outline: 1px dashed } /* for debugging */

.parent {
    background: #f00;
    display: contents;
}

.container {
    background: #0f0;
    width: 25vw;
    display: flex;
}

.object {
    background: #00f;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.object.flexes-main-axis {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.object.sets-cross-axis-size {
    height: 75px;
}

.object.shrinks-cross-axis-below-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.child {
    background: #f0f;
    height: 100%; /* Changed from 100px */
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div id="object1" class='object flexes-main-axis sets-cross-axis-size'>1</div>
        <div id="object2" class='object shrinks-cross-axis-below-content'>
            <div class="child">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have clarified, the magenta box represents an image of fixed size that I cannot change.

Comment: It’s object2 I want to shrink, not child.